# Determine whether Arduino Uno board is faulty or not?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm just giving 9V supply to the Arduino Uno but along with its power led,  the transmission one is also blinking. Can anyone please tell me whether the board is faulty or not?

Comment: The RX and 'L' leds are off and the TX led is blinking and the power led is on? Then there is probably a sketch in the arduino uno that sends something to the serial monitor.

Comment: Use Arduino IDE, connect your Arduino to the PC, load examples -> Blink, program your Arduino and check if it does what supposed to do (if Blink loaded, then LED should blink only)

Comment: from the vast depth of information you have given, I can definitely tell you that the two LED's are not faulty

Comment: nobody can tell you whether the board is faulty  .... you have to  test it yourself